# What is the performance difference between native Canvas api and html5 canvas API for android?

Tags: android

I have non-interactive 2d animation application using html5 canvas and it works great under desktop browsers but performance is miserable under android. How does the performance of android native  [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) vs html5 canvas compare? Since the API is radically different before I spend all the efforts I am posting this question. Is there alternative native android API that is very similar to html5 canvas for 2d animations applications?

Comment: The native API will probably perform better, but it depends on the device too. Desktop browsers will run on desktop computers which will have a lot more power.

Answer (score 1):

My anwser is that the Native One of Android is MUCH MORE SLOWER than js canvas...

Unbelievable !!!

Here is the result of drawing a simple rectangle for 1000 times on my machine

1: Using View and onDraw : costs 5~7s

2: Using Native Canvas(singleton) and a dummy bitmap(singleton), Paint(singleton) and Thread. 3~6s

3: Using Javascript and createElement : 1.1s

4: Using Javascript and canvas : 0.1~0.2s

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with android browser and its canvas implementation. With a xoom (dual cpu), canvas performances are ugly compared to an plain old iPad v1.